# Why doesn't jQuery dialog open event fire when .dialog("open") is called?

Tags: jquery, events, dialog

I define a #scan-date-select dialog in the code below. When I define this dialog, I attach an "open" event handler that is supposed to create a datepicker widget that should appear inside the dialog. The dialog opens correctly, but this open event never gets called. I need to know why the open event handler is failing to get triggered. I have spent two days trying to figure out what is wrong.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="footer_all_pro clearfix">
         <ul class="Printing-options clearfix">
         <li>Shipping Labels:</li>
                    <li class="print-usps-label shipper-logo"><a href="#"><img class="print-label-logo" src="/dev/skin/images/logo_endicia.png"></a></li>
                            <li class="print-label shipper-logo"><a href="#"><img class="print-label-logo" src="/dev/skin/images/logo_ups.png"></a></li>
                            <li class="print-fed-label shipper-logo"><a href="#"><img class="print-label-logo" src="/dev/skin/images/logo_fedex.png"></a></li>
                   <li class="print-invoice"><a href="#">Packing Slip</a></li>
         <li class="print-pick"><a href="#">Pick List</a></li>
                    <li class="print-scan"><a href="#">SCAN Report</a></li>
                   <li class="del-scr"><span><img src="/dev/skin/images/print-pick.png"></span><a href="#" style="margin-top: -20px;">Delete</a></li>
          <li class="del-arc"><span><img src="/dev/skin/images/print-pick.png"></span><a href="#" style="margin-top: -20px;">Archive</a></li>
          <li class="send_email"><span><img src="/dev/skin/images/print-pick.png"></span><a href="#" style="margin-top: -20px;">Send Email</a></li>
         <!-- <li class="del-all-inv"><span><img src="/dev/skin/images/print-pick.png" /></span><a href="#" style="margin-top: -20px;">Delete All</a></li>-->
         </ul>
          </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
  $( ".print-scan a" ).click(function(e) {
        var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
                      .dialog({
title: "Confirm SCAN Report",
modal: false, 
resizable: false,
scrollable: true,
width: 300, 
height: 250,
position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: "article#dialog" },
buttons: { "No": function() { $( this ).dialog( "destroy" ); return false; }, 
           "Yes": function() {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
        $("<div id=\"scan-date-select\"></div>")
        .dialog({ 
                title: "Select SCAN Date", 
                modal: true, 
                resizable: false,
                position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: "article#dialog" },
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    var $rptDate = $("#scan-date-select .ui-dialog-content") //$(this)
                        .datepicker({ autoSize: true })
                        .datepicker("show");
console.log($(this));
console.log($rptDate);
                    //return false;
                },
                buttons: {  Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog("destroy"); return false; },
                            "Create Report": function() {
                                var selectedDate = $rptDate.datepicker("getDate");
                                if(selectedDate == null) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                $(".request-print-label")
                                    .attr("action",envPath + "/partner/uspsscan")
                                    .append('<input type="hidden" name="rpt-date" value="'+selectedDate+'" />')
                                    .submit();

                                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                                return false;
                            }
                }
            })
            .html("<div style=\"padding: 15px\">Please select a transaction date for the SCAN Report</div>")
            .dialog("open");
        }
      }
    })
    .html("<div id=\"confirm-scan\" style=\"padding: 15px\">CAUTION: Once shipping labels are included on the SCAN Report, you will be unable to issue refunds for these labels. Proceed anyway?</div>")
    .dialog("open");
    });
```

Comment: If you don't get the answer in a few days, drop me an @Fluffeh and I will post a bounty on it for you. Should get some more views.

Comment: Create a complete example. You can tell your example is complete if everything can be loaded here: http://jsfiddle.net/ Then people can tell what version of everything you're using, etc.

Comment: These are good ideas. I will follow up on Monday. Thanks.